# Control LCD brightness?

Tags: hdmi, screen, lvds

Is there a way to programmatically control LCD brightness of the screen connected to RPI over HDMI? As far as I could figure there is really no way to achieve this with RPI over HDMI. What about RPI HDMI to LVDS boards? Does this method give this control? There is [a board by chalk-elec](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/HDMI-to-LVDS-converter/p/14647633/category=3094859) that mentions this capability yet I would still like to understand if getting this board is my only way of controlling the brightness of the screen.

Comment: There is not really enough information to give an answer.  Is this a random LCD you have connected to the Pi?  How is it connected?  Do you mean your HDMI monitor screen?  Some details are needed.