# Control LCD brightness via Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, hdmi, display

I have bought a [display from Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/2395). It is a HDMI 7 inch touchscreen display. Is it possible to control the brightness of the display via written software on Raspberry Pi OS? If so, any advice or pointers?

I believe [this question was asked before](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23815/control-lcd-brightness) on this site but no response was given.

Comment: Doesn't the vendor know?

Comment: You will have to generate pwm output to get varying brightness and for that you will need additional circuit. I've used this driver card before. Unfortunately, datasheet is in chinese. Try to get english version from adafruit and you're good go.

Comment: @dastaan https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2299/c2731.pdf this would be the english version but what am i looking for?

Comment: @dastaan my idea would be to try and rewire the buttons that controls the brightness into the GPIO pins of the raspberry Pi and write a software to control the brightness from there .

Comment: @peekaboo The one you attached is for lcd module. You will need an English version of PCB800099 (driver module).

Comment: Which forum are you referring to? Can you edit your question to provide a link to the question?

Comment: @Greenonline http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23815/control-lcd-brightness

similar post that was unanswered

Comment: @dastaan if i were to look at the mandarin version of the http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/PCB800099.pdf driver module what should i be looking for? as I have friends who can read mandarin and  might be able to help me translate

Comment: @peekaboo Have a look at this link. http://tech.mattmillman.com/lcd/pcb800099/ There is some discussion about controlling brightness and switching on / off LCD. That's it. Looks like someone's trying to achieve the same as you're. Controlling it by RPi. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also go through this one. https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=61440